# Android: Sending data to Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, textview

I'm trying to simply send data from my Activity class to my fragment, but when I'm trying to call "setText(String text)" in my fragment the program crashes.

ActivityClass:

```
Fragment_green green = new Fragment_green();
        transaction.replace(R.id.infoFragment, green);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
        transaction.commit();
        green.setText("bar"); //Works okay this far
```

My Fragment_green:

```
public class Fragment_green extends Fragment {

String textShow;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_green, container, false);
}

public void setText(String text){
    TextView textView = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.textGreen);
    textView.setText(text); //Crash :(
}}
```

Everything else works. I can change the fragment to another and so on.
I've seen a few similar posts, but when I'm trying to implent those, other problems occur.

I appreciate all helpfull answers!

Comment: Could we get the crash log? My guess is the textview is null, but it would be easier to tell if we could see the exception.

Comment: http://pastebin.ca/2477331

the textView returns null for som reason, you're right. Any idea how to fix this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're certain the textview is in your fragment layout, then its probably a lifecycle error. The fragment's view hasn't been inflated when you try to access the textview.

Passing information to a fragment this way isn't recommended. Try passing the string through a bundle, and setting the text in the textview when onCreateView is called.